# Best install flow for a new rvm/ruby/pg/rails setup

Tags: ruby, macos, postgresql, rvm

I've reformatted my Mac Mountain Lion machine due to lots errors in rails development, broken links, outdated versions, etc, etc. I'm trying to install RVM, Ruby, Postgresl and Rails. I've installed xcode command line tools and I'm looking for recommendations on which order to install the rest to reduce the likelihood that one can't find the other.

Should I install homebrew before any of these? I've read RVM has a new package manager with it that will do most of that stuff, even install homebrew - and not being a unix expert that is appealing. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Also would anyone recommend installing postgres before RVM or after RVM/Ruby/Rails is set up?

Comment: It doesn't matter when you install PG. Obviously Rails would come last with regards to the Ruby-related stuff, and RVM first. Homebrew is orthogonal, I'd install it first since it can be used to install other things.

Comment: So weird, to reformat. Couldn't you just `rm -rf /usr/local`?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/auvm9g (except for postgres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Xcode with command line tools
2. Homebrew
3. Git
4. RVM
5. Ruby
6. Rails
7. Postgres

You may at some point get a WARNING form Nokogiri about it being built with one version of LibXML but dynamically loaded with another.  You are pretty much stuck with whatever version is being dynamically linked because the MacOS depends on it and it is loaded during boot and Nokogiri needs to be dynamically linked.  If you are starting new with Mountain Lion you should be OK.  If not, there are dozens of variations of solutions that all amount to compiling Nokogiri against whatever version of LibXML you have in your OS.  Hopefully all you need to do if you do run into this problem at some point is

```
bundle exec gem pristine nokogiri
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I went with, so far they are all playing nice.